# Fourier series from wikipedia

Tags: fourier-series

How did this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) come up with the Fourier coefficients? It basically jump after coming up with this $$A_n=\sqrt{a^2_n+b^2_n} , \quad\phi_n=\arctan\left(\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right).$$

Comment: Are you asking how they derived it in terms of the integral?

Comment: Wikipedia is not really a textbook, it doesn't have to prove everything, just provide the proper sources for any claim. I suggest you look at a textbook (calculus textbook or a more advanced textbook about Fourier series)

Comment: As it stands, the question is not good. If you just want a proof, then get rid of the condition that it should be the one supposedly used on the Wikipedia page.